# Why does only "else" statement execute?

Tags: javascript

In this code I created objects, which contain adjectives, or nouns in different gender. I also typed *"beautiful maxim"*, and despite the fact that EnAdjectives has *"beautiful"* and *"maxim"* belongs to "*EnMaleNouns"*, `else` statement executes.

```
let EnMaleNouns = {...};
let EnAdjectives = {...};

function conj() {
    let sentence = document.getElementById("input_one").value.split(" ").filter(item => item != "")
    let final = [];
    for (let word in sentence) {
        for (let key in EnAdjectives) {
            if (sentence[word] == key && sentence[++word] in EnMaleNouns) {
                //do something
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix that, and why this is happening?

Comment: probably because you use `++word` in every test ... use `word+1` instead and refactor the code so it's not doing `++word` so many times

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work(

Comment: well, that suggests none of the conditions are met - should they be? perhaps `console.log(sentence[word], sentence[word_1] in EnMaleNouns, sentence[word_1] in EnFemaleNouns, sentence[word_1] in EnNeuterNouns)` before the first if, and see if the result is what you expect

Comment: Because you `break;` on every branch of the if statement you only execute both loops once. Maybe that helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is a `for in` loop. So key will be holding index position as values i.e `key = [0,1]`. So in your if condition it is compared as `'beautiful' == 0` which will never be true. So the else block is executing everytime.

---

**Solution:**
Use a for of loop for your inner loop as

```
for(let key of EnAdjectives)
```